why the pyttsx3 module is not running properly?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sudip Chakraborty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Sudip Chakraborty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\ankur\1vs code\arduino projects\image_detection\test3.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\Sudip Chakraborty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Sudip Chakraborty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Sudip Chakraborty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Sudip Chakraborty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Sudip Chakraborty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Users\Sudip Chakraborty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.


I'm getting this error . I've already installed all the packages and all
already tried :-
uninstalling and reinstalling, downgrading version to 2.71, editing the code to include, tried installing pywin32(already present)
1.
engine=pyttsx3.init('dummy')




engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

expecting :-
to hear voice
